# React Hooks D3 and Isotope libraries owning state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks, jquery-isotope

I am trying to refactor my existing code to use Hooks instead of constructors, componentDidMount(), componentDidUpdate(). My original code below did this just fine:

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/App.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import Isotope from 'isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js';  
import projectsData from '../data/projectsData';
import Project from './Projects';

    class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      isotope: null,
    projectComponents: projectsData.map(project => <Project id={project.id} project={project}/>),
  }
 }

  componentDidMount() {

    //load isotope masonry view
    const elem = document.querySelector('#visContainer')
    if (!this.state.isotope) {
      this.setState({
        isotope: new Isotope( elem, {
          //options
          itemSelector: '.gridItem',
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 140,
            fitWidth: true
          },
          getSortData: {
            year: '.yearsstart parseFloat',
            kind: '.kind'
          }
        })
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.isotope.reloadItems();
    }
  }
  }
    componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.state.isotope) {
        this.state.isotope.reloadItems();
        this.state.isotope.layout();
      }
    }
  render(){


    return (
      <body>
        <div id='sepLine'>
        <div id="visHolder">
           <div id="visContainer" style={{position: "relative", width: "840px", height: "1823px"}}>
             {this.state.projectComponents} 
           </div>           
         </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
 
}

export default App
```

However, I am trying to amend this to use d3 library instead of mapping an outside component (Projects). **And do this with React Hooks.** What I have below maps the data using d3 but I am unable to apply Isotope to the id "visContainer".
I suspect it is because they are happening at the same time as they are both using useEffect()?:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import '../css/App.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import Isotope from 'isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js';  
import projectsData from '../data/projectsData';
import Project from './Projects';

function App () {
  const [isotope, setIsotope] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const projects = d3.select('#visContainer');
    projects
    .selectAll('.lineDiv')
    .data(projectsData)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('id', (d,i) => { 
      return d.title })
        .attr('className', d => {
      return 'lineDiv gridItem y' + d.start.substring(0,4) + ' ' + d.kind + ' ' + d.title + ' ' + d.subtitle.replace(/, /g, ' ');
    })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const elem = document.querySelector('#visContainer')  
      setIsotope(new Isotope( elem, {
          itemSelector: '.gridItem',
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 140,
            fitWidth: true
          },
          getSortData: {
            year: '.yearsstart parseFloat',
            kind: '.kind'
          }
        })
      )
    },[]);
    return (
      <body>
        <div id='sepLine'>
        <div id="visHolder">
           <div id="visContainer" style={{position: "relative", width: "840px", height: "1823px"}}>
           </div>           
         </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    );
  }

export default App
```

Any help would be really appreciated as I am keen to learn how far I can push React Hooks. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by using "useEffect" on intial load to setProjects() with mapping. Then Isotope takes control of the '#visContainer' with

```
document.querySelector('#visContainer')
```

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(null);
  const [isotope, setIsotope] = useState(null);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects(projectsData.map(project => <Project id={project.id} project={project} onClick={filterThisProject}/>))
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    const elem = document.querySelector('#visContainer')  
      setIsotope(new Isotope( elem, {
          itemSelector: '.gridItem',
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 140,
            fitWidth: true
          },
          getSortData: {
            year: '.start parseFloat',
            kind: '.kind'
          }
        })
      )
    },[projects]);


    return (
      <body>
        <div id='sepLine'>
        <div id="visHolder">
           <div id="visContainer" style={{position: "relative", width: "840px", height: "1823px"}} >
             {projects}
           </div>           
         </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    );
}

export default App;
```